# Como abrir uma webview local cshtml no Xamarin Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin-forms, webview

Estou com um projeto em Asp net mvc e outro em Xamarin Forms, preciso chamar no meu projeto Xamarin Forms uma WebView Local porem a pagina está como cshtml (asp net)

Comment: Você não pode abrir diretamente a View, vai precisar indicar a URL para da action no site mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vai rolar. `cshtml` é uma extensão de arquivo de projeto que precisa ser **compilado**, **publicado** em um servidor asp.net para que no momento da **requisição web** seja processado e só então a página HTML seja entregue para o cliente (no seu caso a webview).

Na melhor das hipóteses o que você vai conseguir é navegar em conteúdo html baseado em arquivos dentro do proprio aplicativo, mas é difícil dizer se isso lhe atenderia somente com as informações que foram fornecidas até o momento.

Comment: Entendi, estou utilizando agora o html, porem estou com problema para chamar a webview local em cada aplicativo utilizando Dependencia como sugerido na documentação da microsoft

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=vswin

Comment: Gravidade Código Descrição Projeto Arquivo Linha Estado de Supressão
Erro CS7036 Não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário "loadHintArgument" de "DependencyAttribute.DependencyAttribute(string, LoadHint)" AppFrete.UWP 
Erro CS7036 Não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário "loadHintArgument" de "DependencyAttribute.DependencyAttribute(string, LoadHint)" AppFrete.iOS

Comment: Erro CS1061 "MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl" não contém uma definição para "BaseUrl" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "BaseUrl" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl" (há uma diretiva de uso ou referência de assembly ausente?) AppFrete


Print do código
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdunfahoco6xy46/erro.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @ViniciusDantas, beleza. Abre uma outra pergunta sobre o novo erro que você está enfrentando, já que isso está fora do escopo desta thread aqui. Veremos se vamos consiguir te ajudar a partir de lá. É dificil fazê-lo sem ver o código que está utilizando.